# C# generate a public and private keys for the DSA encryption algorithm

Tags: c#, encryption, public-key-encryption, dsa

How do I generate a public and a private key for the DSA algorithm in byte array format?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In DSA algorithm ([from wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Signature_Algorithm)):

- Public key is (p, q, g, y).
- Private key is x.

  ```
      var dsa = new DSACryptoServiceProvider();            
      var privateKey = dsa.ExportParameters(true); // private key
      var publicKey = dsa.ExportParameters(false); // public key
  ```

In publicKey it's P, Q, G, Y propertyes

In privateKey it's X

And don't forget to accept this answer!